# Finding 90th percentile when data is in aggregated format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in following format:

| Score | Count of student |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 12 |
| 99 | 32 |
| 98 | 13 |
| 97 | 12 |
| 96 | 33 |
| 95 | 42 |
| 94 | 13 |
| 93 | 14 |

Basically score and a count of student scoring that much score.
How do I find 90th percentile score on this data.
I tried to google this and found `PERCENTILE_DISC` and `PERCENTILE_CONT` but not sure how to use them in this data?

For above data total student count comes out to be 171. 90th percentile score will be 99 in this example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Docs here are pretty straightforward https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @AleixCC I only skimmed, but doesn't that require each entry have its own row (which the SQL server can then group), instead of a count of how many entries have that value? I suspect you can do this in SQL using temporary tables and such, though using a procedural language would probably be easier.